# My Shared Preferences Showing All Escaped Characters (&quot ;) Rather Than Quotation Marks

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm writing an application to store vehicle information using Gson/Json and Shared Preferences in Kotlin using Android Studio (Latest Version) and I've finally gotten the code to work but the strings that are saved in my sharedpreferences file (json arrays and objects) have now started showing the escape characters for quotation marks (&quot ;) rather than the quotation marks it's shown all along.. Can anybody tell me why? Program works fine, but it's really hard for me to read the xml file.

I've searched and searched but can't find a reason this may be happening. Sorry, new to Android Studio and Kotlin.